# How to update existing array of arrays with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

In a Laravel project I have an array with arrays like this:

```
$results = [

    0 => [
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'category_ids' => [1,3,5,20]
    ],
    1 => [
        'title' => 'Example title 2',
        'category_ids' => [4,8,21]
    ],
    3 => [
        'title' => 'Example title 3',
        'category_ids' => [1,3,5,20]
    ],

];
```

How can I add another field `category_names` based on these ids? I have a database that has the corresponding Id to the name of the category. So the array can look like this:

```
$results = [

    0 => [
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'category_ids' => [1,3,5,20],
        'category_names' => ['Fiction', 'Novel', 'Narrative', 'Mystery']
    ],
    1 => [
        'title' => 'Example title 2',
        'category_ids' => [4,8,21],
        'category_names' => ['Something', 'Else', 'Different']
    ],
    2 => [
        'title' => 'Example title 3',
        'category_ids' => [1,3,5,20],
        'category_names' => ['Fiction', 'Novel', 'Narrative', 'Mystery']
    ],

];
```

So far I have tried with foreach loops, but can't figure out how to put the array back together and if it is efficient enough. If there are 300 results will this foreach loops take much resources?

```
foreach($results as $result){

   $categoris = $results['category_ids'];
   $category_names = [];

   foreach($categoris  as $category){
     $cat = Category::where('category_id', $category)->first()->name;
     
     $category_names[] = $cat;
   }


}
```

Comment: How are you updating `category_ids`

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Comment: @JohnDoe I have updated the question to write what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map` with `foreach`

```
foreach($results as &$val){
 $val['category_names'] = array_map(function($v) use ($categories){
    return $categories[$v];
 }, $val['category_ids']);
}
```

Working Example :- https://3v4l.org/YtqRE

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Can I something. What is the `&` character in the foreach loop ? I noticed that without it, it is not working?

Comment: @DarkBoss This is called `pass by reference`, we are modifying the existing array with a new index to add `category_names`

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = [
  0 => [
    'title' => 'Some title',
    'category_ids' => [1, 3, 5, 20]
  ],
  
  1 => [
    'title' => 'Example title 2',
    'category_ids' => [4, 8, 21]
  ],
  
  3 => [
    'title' => 'Example title 3',
    'category_ids' => [1, 3, 5, 20]
  ],

];

foreach ($results as $key =>$result) {
  $results[$key]['category_names'] = ['Fiction', 'Novel', 'Narrative', 'Mystery'];
}
```